# C++ custom time date struct to utc epoch

Tags: c++, c++11, timestamp, c++-chrono, time-t

I use a library that uses the following struct to define a start timestamp as follows.

```
    struct SYSTEMTIME {
    /** year */
    WORD year;

    /** month */
    WORD month;

    /** day of week */
    WORD dayOfWeek;

    /** day */
    WORD day;

    /** hour */
    WORD hour;

    /** minute */
    WORD minute;

    /** second */
    WORD second;

    /** milliseconds */
    WORD milliseconds;
};
```

For every log entry after this time is specified in nanoseconds difference from this first timestamp.

Lets say its UTC 2017-12-19 14:44:00
And the first following log entries are 397000ns after this.

How do I create a chronos, time_t or unix time from epoch from the first SYSTEMTIME struct and then add the nanoseconds to it.

Printout should be for this first entry
2017-12-19 14:44:00.000397

Best regards

Comment: I would go the other direction where i start with an unix timestamp and convert it into year, month, etc. if necessary. This might be a bit more straightforward.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible due to the library i'm using. So I need to construct a unix timestamp for that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

I've slightly modified the code below to convert between `SYSTEMTIME` and `date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>`, instead of `date::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds>`.

*Rationale:*  So that there is no implicit precision loss in `to_SYSTEMTIME`.  Clients of `to_SYSTEMTIME` can explicitly truncate precision in any way that they desire (`floor`, `round`, `ceil`, etc.).  And failure to truncate precision (if needed) won't be a silent run time error.

The client code (in `main`) is not impacted by this change.

---

You could use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) for this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

using WORD = int;

struct SYSTEMTIME {
    /** year */
    WORD year;

    /** month */
    WORD month;

    /** day of week */
    WORD dayOfWeek;

    /** day */
    WORD day;

    /** hour */
    WORD hour;

    /** minute */
    WORD minute;

    /** second */
    WORD second;

    /** milliseconds */
    WORD milliseconds;
};

date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>
to_sys_time(SYSTEMTIME const& t)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    return sys_days{year{t.year}/t.month/t.day} + hours{t.hour} +
           minutes{t.minute} + seconds{t.second} + milliseconds{t.milliseconds};
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    SYSTEMTIME st{2017, 12, 2, 19, 14, 44, 0, 0};
    auto t = to_sys_time(st) + 397000ns;
    std::cout << floor<microseconds>(t) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2017-12-19 14:44:00.000397
```

This converts a `SYSTEMTIME` to a `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>` (which has a type-alias named `date::sys_time<milliseconds>`) by collecting the different parts out of the `SYSTEMTIME`.  It then simply adds `nanoseconds` to that `time_point`, truncates it to the desired precision of `microseconds`, and streams it out.

If it would be helpful, here is how you could use the same library to do the opposite conversion:

```
SYSTEMTIME
to_SYSTEMTIME(date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds> const& t)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    auto sd = floor<days>(t);
    year_month_day ymd = sd;
    auto tod = make_time(t - sd);
    SYSTEMTIME x;
    x.year = int{ymd.year()};
    x.month = unsigned{ymd.month()};
    x.dayOfWeek = weekday{sd}.c_encoding();
    x.day = unsigned{ymd.day()};
    x.hour = tod.hours().count();
    x.minute = tod.minutes().count();
    x.second = tod.seconds().count();
    x.milliseconds = tod.subseconds().count();
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mktime()` from `<ctime>` to convert `tm`, to `time_t`, which is an integer type.

`tm` is very simmilar to your `SYSTEMTIME` struct. Therefore you sould be able to translate them easily back and forth.

translate your struct into tm and then use `gmtime()` like this.

```
#include <ctime>

struct tm time = fromSystemtime(...);
time_t timestamp;

timestamp = mktime(&time);
```

For more details see the following links:

[struct tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/)

[time_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/)

[mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/)